# How many permutations with a given number of disjoint cycles are there?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups

Let $S^n$ be the symmentric group. How to count the number of permutations in $S^n$ having exactly $c$ disjoint cycles? Counting the permutations with $c$ or more/fewer disjoint cycles would be fine as well.

Comment: Look for **Stirling numbers of the first kind.**